# Error when adding Log4J dependencies to Maven project

Tags: maven, logging, javafx, log4j, log4j2

Im new to maven/log4J and Im trying to add Log4J to my maven project and it runs and compiles fine without the log4J dependencies but when i try adding it it gives out this error code

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules jfxrt and javafx.graphics export package javafx.stage to module javafx.swt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Ive tried to do some research but im not really finding anything relating to that.
this is my pom.xml File w/ the log4J dependency being the last dependency added on here.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If anyone can help explain whats going on it would be greatly appreciated.

here is whats inside my module-info.java

```
module org.example {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens org.example to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.example;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file? Have you tried adding a require statement requiring log4j to it?

Comment: @AllanJuan yes ill edit the code on here to display whats inside module-info.java

Comment: Yeah, in this case I suggest you add `requires org.apache.logging.log4j-core` to it and see what happens.

Comment: @AllanJuan throws a syntax error